# how to improve performance of boost::spirit::x3 key-value parser

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-spirit-x3

I am parsing key value pairs (similar to HTTP headers) using `boost::spirit::x3`. When comparing the performance to my handwritten parser, `boost::spirit::x3` is around 10% slower than that.

I am using boost 1.61 and GCC 6.1:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -I/tmp/boost_1_61_0/boost/ main.cpp  && ./a.out

phrase_parse 1.97432 microseconds
parseHeader 1.75742 microseconds
```

How can I improve the performance of the `boost::spirit::x3` based parser?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>

using header_map = std::map<std::string, std::string>; 

namespace parser
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    using x3::char_;
    using x3::lexeme;

    x3::rule<class map, header_map> const map = "msg";

    const auto key     = +char_("0-9a-zA-Z-");
    const auto value   = +~char_("\r\n");

    const auto header =(key >> ':' >> value >> lexeme["\r\n"]);
    const auto map_def = *header >> lexeme["\r\n"];

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(map);
}


template <typename It>
void parseHeader(It& iter, It end, header_map& map)
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;

    It last = iter;
    bool inKey = true;
    while(iter+1 != end)
    {
        if(inKey && *(iter+1)==':')
        {
            key.assign(last, iter+1);
            iter+=3;
            last = iter;
            inKey = false;
        }
        else if (!inKey && *(iter+1)=='\r' && *(iter+2)=='\n')
        {
            value.assign(last, iter+1);
            map.insert({std::move(key), std::move(value)});
            iter+=3;
            last = iter;
            inKey = true;
        }
        else if (inKey && *(iter)=='\r' && *(iter+1)=='\n') 
        {
            iter+=2;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ++iter;
        }
    }
}

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
double benchmark(F func, Args&&... args)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    constexpr auto num = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);

    return duration.count() / (double)num;
}

int main()
{
    const std::size_t headerCount = 20;

    std::string str;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < headerCount; ++i)
    {
        std::string num = std::to_string(i);
        str.append("key" + num + ": " + "value" + num + "\r\n");
    }
    str.append("\r\n");

    double t1 = benchmark([&str]() {
        auto iter = str.cbegin();
        auto end = str.cend();

        header_map header;
        phrase_parse(iter, end, parser::map, boost::spirit::x3::ascii::blank, header);
        return header;
    });
    std::cout << "phrase_parse " << t1 << " microseconds"<< std::endl;

    double t2 = benchmark([&str]() {
        auto iter = str.cbegin();
        auto end = str.cend();

        header_map header;
        parseHeader(iter, end, header);
        return header;
    });
    std::cout << "parseHeader " << t2 << " microseconds"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12ef58fb74744364)**

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fixed x3 grammar that comes a lot closer to your hand rolled "parser":

```
const auto key     = +~char_(':');
const auto value   = *(char_ - "\r\n");

const auto header = key >> ':' >> value >> "\r\n";
const auto map    = *header >> "\r\n";
```

Of course, it's still more strict and more robust. Also, don't call it with a space skipper, since your hand-rolled parser doesn't do that either.

Here's the performance measurements on my box:

[image]

Statistics that's 2.5µs vs. 3.5µs on average.

### Full Code

Using http://nonius.io for robust benchmarking:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>

using header_map = std::map<std::string, std::string>; 

namespace parser
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    using x3::char_;

    const auto key     = +~char_(':');
    const auto value   = *(char_ - "\r\n");

    const auto header = key >> ':' >> value >> "\r\n";
    const auto map    = *header >> "\r\n";
}


template <typename It>
void parseHeader(It& iter, It end, header_map& map)
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;

    It last = iter;
    bool inKey = true;
    while(iter+1 != end)
    {
        if(inKey && *(iter+1)==':')
        {
            key.assign(last, iter+1);
            iter+=3;
            last = iter;
            inKey = false;
        }
        else if (!inKey && *(iter+1)=='\r' && *(iter+2)=='\n')
        {
            value.assign(last, iter+1);
            map.insert({std::move(key), std::move(value)});
            iter+=3;
            last = iter;
            inKey = true;
        }
        else if (inKey && *(iter)=='\r' && *(iter+1)=='\n') 
        {
            iter+=2;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ++iter;
        }
    }
}

static auto const str = [] {
    std::string tmp;
    const std::size_t headerCount = 20;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < headerCount; ++i)
    {
        std::string num = std::to_string(i);
        tmp.append("key" + num + ": " + "value" + num + "\r\n");
    }
    tmp.append("\r\n");
    return tmp;
}();

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("manual", [](nonius::chronometer cm) {

    cm.measure([]() {
        auto iter = str.cbegin();
        auto end = str.cend();

        header_map header;
        parseHeader(iter, end, header);
        assert(header.size() == 20);
        return header.size();
    });
})

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("x3", [](nonius::chronometer cm) {

    cm.measure([] {
        auto iter = str.cbegin();
        auto end = str.cend();

        header_map header;
        parse(iter, end, parser::map, header);
        assert(header.size() == 20);
        return header.size();
    });
})

#include <nonius/main.h++>
```

I'm using gcc 5.4 and Boost 1.61

Comment: Do you have measurements for the original grammar on your machine as well?

Comment: @m.s. Note [that](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23108234/) "randomly" strips whitespace from inside keys/values: 3.6µs too. Graph: http://i.imgur.com/undefined.jpg

Comment: Regardless of everything, you should profile for the bottleneck first, I think. It's bound to be allocations. I'd suggest parsing to string_ref/string_view if possible and maybe reserved flat_map: [brings the manual version under 2µs](http://i.imgur.com/qzv1LZ6.png) with this code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23108281/

Comment: What exactly strips whitespace?

Comment: The skipper that you pass to phrase_parse

Comment: I tried profiling but most of the code is inlined and callgrind does not produce much useful output for that.

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how to use x3 with string_view?

Comment: @m.s. : You can use the `raw` directive, which gives you a `boost::iterator_range`, which in turn is trivially convertible into a string_view.

Answer (score 0):

After having a first look over the custom parser it occurs to me that it is not as robust as the spirit parser.

If you change line 91 to remove the `\r` from the trailing `"\r\n"` you'll see what I mean.

Bad data can cause the hand-rolled one to segfault.

e.g.:

```
str.append("key" + num + ": " + "value" + num + "\n");
```

results in segfault on line 46.

So step one, I think, is to modify the hand-rolled parser so that it's checking boundary conditions in the same way that the spirit one is.

Although I don't expect the timings to converge completely, they will be closer.

Comment: you are right, the hand written parser is not as robust as the spirit one, e.g. there is also no validation of key strings (`"0-9a-zA-Z-"`); however, there might still be improvements possible for the `spirit::x3` based, e.g. a different skipper, etc. this kind of advice is what I am looking for

Comment: @m.s. you could try simple `parse()` and skip the whitespace explicitly? However, from my experience (and the advice I have received), it's rarely faster. sprit uses the blindingly fast standard lib under the cover for it's default white-space skipper.

Comment: @m.s. but the first problem (to reiterate) is that you're not comparing like with like. So you have no data for how fast the spirit version *could or should be*, since there is no handwritten baseline to compare against.